# Why is my nested while loop not working python?

Tags: python

So i'm making a rock paper game,I have added my source code. So far I have made the players enter their choices. I tried adding a check to make sure the choices they enter is one of the three. My program corrects it once, and then it stops doing anything

[image: This is what happens, and it just stays like this until I force exit]

Here is my source code.

```
print('''Please pick one of the following:
Rock
Paper
Scissors''')
p1 = None
p2 = None
while True:
    gameDict = {"rock":1,"paper":2,"scissors":3}
    in1 = input("Player 1: ").lower()
    in2 = input("Player 2: ").lower()
    p1 = gameDict.get(in1)
    p2 =gameDict.get(in2)
    while gameDict.get(p1)==None or gameDict.get(p2)==None:
        if(p1==None):
            p1=input("Player 1, please enter one of the choices listed above: ")
        elif p2== None:
            p2=input("Player 2, please enter one of the choices listed above: ")
    print('Done!!')
    print(p1,p2)
```

Comment: `p1 = gameDict.get(in1)` and `gameDict.get(p1)`? Does that really make sense?

Comment: Yes i think you want to try p1 == None or p2 == None and do in1 = input(...), In2==input ...

Comment: What would be a better way to test the input and make sure its one of the three choices?

Comment: OMG! I see it now!! thank you guys so much.

Answer (score 2):

It's not that it's not doing anything. In fact it's doing a lot, it's in an infinite loop. What happens when a wrong input is entered is:

- `p1 = None`, `p2 = None`.
- In the first iteration, since `p1 == None` evaluates to `true`, it executes the `if` statement, a new value is assigned to `p1` and now it's not `None` anymore.
- In the second iteration, `p2 == None` evaluates to `true`, it executes the `if` statement, a new value is assigned to `p2` and now it's not `None` anymore.
- After that, both `p1` and `p2` are not `None`, and thus none of the `if` statements gets executed and the loop iterates infinitely.

I suggest you do the following:

```
print('''Please pick one of the following:
Rock
Paper
Scissors''')
p1 = None
p2 = None

while True:
    gameDict = {"rock":1, "paper":2, "scissors":3}
    in1 = input("Player 1: ").lower()
    in2 = input("Player 2: ").lower()
    p1 = gameDict.get(in1)
    p2 = gameDict.get(in2)

    while p1 ==None or p2 ==None:
        if(p1 == None):
          val = input("Player 1, please enter one of the choices listed above: ")
          if(gameDict.get(val) != None):
            p1 = val

        if p2 == None:
          val = input("Player 2, please enter one of the choices listed above: ")
          if(gameDict.get(val) != None):
            p2 = val

    print('Done!!')
    print(p1, p2)
```

Stuff I have fixed:

1. Made a dedicated variable for the input string value, i.e `val`.
2. Changed `elif` to `if` because either of the players' input can be valid, but not the other and you would want to loop until both are valid.

Answer (score 0):

You compare *keys* entered by the user ("scissors") to the *values* in the dictionary. You need to ensure that the keys are right:

```
while in1 not in gameDict:
    in1 = input("Player 1, please...: ").lower()
while in2 not in gameDict:
    in2 = input("Player 2, please...: ").lower()
```

Once you get valid inputs, you can look them up:

```
p1 = gameDict[in1]
p2 = gameDict[in2]
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this is the right code:
(you should check if **either p1 or p2 is None**)

```
print('''Please pick one of the following:
Rock
Paper
Scissors''')
p1 = None
p2 = None
while True:
    gameDict = {"rock":1,"paper":2,"scissors":3}
    in1 = input("Player 1: ").lower()
    in2 = input("Player 2: ").lower()
    p1 = gameDict.get(in1)
    p2 =gameDict.get(in2)
    while p1==None or p2==None:
        if(p1==None):
            p1=input("Player 1, please enter one of the choices listed above: ")
        elif p2== None:
            p2=input("Player 2, please enter one of the choices listed above: ")
    print('Done!!')
    print(p1,p2)
```